# Reconfiguring Linux server with different IP after installing from AMI image

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-web-services, webmin, virtualmin

I'm a total newbie so any kinda help is highly appreciated.

I used to have an EC2 server in my old AWS account running CentOS 7 (64bit) and a typical LAMP stack with Webmin/Virtualmin and `Elastic IP address A`. It is hosting 3 websites/virtual hosts.

I did an AMI image over it and redeploy the AMI to a new AWS account using a different `Elastic IP B`.

After redeploying, some settings are still using the `old IP address A`. Thus, is there any way to check the entire system to ensure that now the new server and the websites are using the new Elastic IP B or new server? What are the modules should I check? Any online reference available (cos I can't seem to Google any perhaps I'm using wrong keywords)?

P/S: I only know how to use Webmin/Virtualmin.